# Printing unknown number list of words

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

I created a program that checks a text file of how many words of a specific length appear in it. I wanted to print the number of words that my program found of this specific length and then print out that list of words. However, the list of words is printing in my `while` loop first, because I have to print the count outside of this loop. Do I have to make this unknown numbered list into an array and then return the array to print it in the main method in order for this to print second? Here's what I have so far:

```
public static void countLetters(PartArray part, int num) throws Exception{
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("2of12inf.txt"));

int count = 0;
while( inputFile.hasNext() ){
  String word = inputFile.next();

  if (word.length() == num)
  {
    count++;

    expandArray (part , 2*MAX_SIZE);
    System.out.println(word);
  } 
}
System.out.println("I found " + count + " " + num + "-letter words.");
System.out.println("The list of words is: ");
inputFile.close();
```

Comment: Do I have to make this unknown numbered list into an array and then return the array to print it in the main method in order for this to print second? Yes, if you want to print the count first and then the list of words.

Comment: An `ArrayList` is what you're looking for here since the size of the array would not be static.

Comment: Is using an `ArrayList` the only way to do this? My professor recommended not to because he wants us to learn the actual concepts of arrays. I was hoping to make this into an Object and return it and print the array of words. Would that make sense?

Comment: @hello With the code you're currently showing, an `ArrayList` is your best option. The problem is you don't know how many words are going to be returned and an array has a fixed length once created.

Comment: Depending on how big the file is, it may be better to scan through it twice, first time to get the count, second time to print the words out. Otherwise all the time you're building up your array, you're using up memory. However, if the prof wants you to use an array, then I agree with Diptendu above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid printing the words in the while loop, you can take the println out of the loop. You don't have to add each word to a data structure if you don't want to. You can append each word to a "wordBuffer" StringBuffer (String Buffer concatenation is faster and more efficient than a String), for more info on this matter read this: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076072/build-ci-sdlc/stringbuffer-versus-string.html

like this:

```
int count = 0;
StringBuffer wordBuffer = new StringBuffer ("");

while( inputFile.hasNext() ){
  String word = inputFile.next();

  if (word.length() == num)
  {
    count++;
    //Adding \n assuming you want new line between elements
    wordBuffer.append(word+"\n"); 
  } 
}
System.out.println("I found " + count + " " + num + "-letter words.");
System.out.println("The list of words is: "wordBuffer);
inputFile.close();
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: StringBuilder might be even better than StringBuffer. StringBuffer is sychronized, so that you can use it in multi-threaded contexts, but synchronization also adds overhead that's not needed in this case.

Comment: Wow! That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much!! I've never heard of the String method "Buffer", but based on the wonderful link you provided, I was able to just convert it into a code I'm familiar with!!

Comment: @hello I'm glad that helped, I appreciate the check =]

Comment: @hello Glad you got the answer you were looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with arrays in this context is an array has an immutable size once initialized. If you're retrieving a mutable collection, you need a collector that has no such limitation. An `ArrayList` would achieve this.

```
public static void countLetters(PartArray part, int num) throws Exception {
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("2of12inf.txt"));

int count = 0;
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList();

while( inputFile.hasNext() ){
  String word = inputFile.next();

  if (word.length() == num)
  {
    count++;
    //expandArray (part , 2*MAX_SIZE);
    //System.out.println(word);
    words.add(word);//adding each word to a new index with each iteration
  } 
}
System.out.println("I found " + count + " " + num + "-letter words.");
System.out.println("The list of words is: ");

for (String w in words) {//for each word in the words ArrayList
   System.out.println(w);//print out the values
}

inputFile.close();
```